# Do not understand why I should use malloc with a struct with an array of defined length

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, malloc

Recently I got an assignment where I needed to create a structure to store the data of a polygon. My approach was using a flexible array member, like this:

```
struct point {
    float x, y;
};

struct polygon {
    int num_vertex;
    struct point vertex_list[];
};
```

But the teacher in the solution prefered to use an array with a determined size (in order to make it easier I guess). His approach looked like this:

```
#define SIZE 1000

struct point {
    float x, y;
};

struct polygon{
    int num_vertex;
    struct point vertex_list[SIZE];
};
```

So far I understand perfectly what he is doing but when creating a polygon he also used the malloc function in this way:

```
struct polygon p;
p.num_vertex = 6;
p.vertex_list=malloc(p.num_vertex*sizeof(struct point));
```

I don't understand the `malloc` step because as far as I know since we have defined the length of the array in the structure the compiler already knows the needed memory. Something I thought is that maybe by reallocating the memory the part of the memory that we are not going to use will be freed but I am not sure about this. Could you tell me why we are using malloc there?

EDIT: I am being told that this teacher from time to time makes mistakes in the code in order for us to find them and correct them. At least that is what he says. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You cannot assign to arrays. `p.vertex_list=malloc(p.num_vertex*sizeof(struct point));` is invalid for both case.

Comment: Are you sure that's the code your instructor is using?  It won't compile.

Comment: A mistake it is. If your instructor did it on purpose is there to be verified. Your approach is safe. Some people may prefer `typedef`s instead of the structs. If used only inside the polygons the `point` structure can be internal

Comment: What do yo mean by `typedef`s instead of structs? Isn't typedef just used to rename the way we name a type?